# Getting a Research Grant for Carrying out Research as Independent Researcher in my home country

Tags: funding, independent-researcher

I took a mid career break to complete my doctoral research in management of intellectual property rights. 
Currently, I don't have an institutional affiliation though I have a comprehensive experience in research and publications.
How and where can I look for funding to take up a project for a short term?

Comment: How do you not have an institutional affiliation if you are doing doctoral research? Further, any answer would likely be region/country specific, and you have not indicated where you are in the solar system...

Comment: Shopping question ...

Comment: When you got your research doc position surely you were funded for the period?

Answer (score 1):

What he / he meant maybe formal direct affiliation [like employment or permanent affiliation in an institution] Many wanting to do research but funding agencies asked for formal institutional affiliation where the funds can be monitored. Quite difficult to secure funding with this criteria from funding agencies. The best is to look for agencies which provide or support individual research project.